# Add paragraphs to the legalnoticetext (Before Login Screen)

Tags: windows, login-screen

I know how to edit the `legalnoticetext` and how to get it to display before the Windows login screen, my question is how do I separate the paragraphs?

So please, if anyone out there knows of a trick that will display the text nicely formatted with paragraphs like this

> "NOTICE TO USERS
>
> This computer system is the private property of XYZ Pty Ltd, whether
>   individual, corporate or government. This laptop is for authorized use
>   only. Users (authorized or unauthorized) have no explicit or implicit
>   expectation of privacy.
>
> Any or all uses of this system and all files on this system may be
>   intercepted, monitored, recorded, copied, audited, inspected, and
>   disclosed to your employer, to authorized site, government, and law 
>   enforcement personnel, as well as authorized officials of government
>   agencies, both domestic and foreign.
>
> By using this system, the user consents to such interception,
>   monitoring, recording, copying, auditing, inspection, and disclosure
>   at the discretion of such personnel or officials. Unauthorized or
>   improper use of this system may result in civil and criminal penalties
>   and administrative or disciplinary action, as appropriate. By
>   continuing to use this system you indicate your awareness of and
>   consent to these terms and conditions of use. LOG OFF IMMEDIATELY if
>   you do not agree to the conditions stated in this warning."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click on the `LegalNoticeText` entry in Registry Editor, and select **Modify Binary Data**.  Insert hexadecimal `0d 00 0a 00` where you want a new line, and `0d 00 0a 00 0d 00 0a 00` where you want a empty line separating two paragraphs.  This code must be inserted after the `00` of the hexadecimal code which corresponds to the character in the text.  Windows uses [little-endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16), where two bytes represent each character, in this and related registry entries, and `0d 00 0a 00` is the UTF-16 code for newline on Windows systems.

This is more clearly explained in this Microsoft Support article: [How to Add a Carriage Return to the Legal Notice Text in Windows NT](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/238149)

Comment: Somehow I seem to be unable to do this (I get Chinese characters), could you please elaborate and explain where I should insert the hexadecimal data. Thanks

Comment: Windows uses [little-endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) in these registry entries.  Each character is represented by two bytes.  The `0d 00 0a 00` must come after the `00` of the preceding character.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit dated, but just press paste into Notepad and use Shift+Enter when creating spaces. Copy and paste into the registry. All set.