# Is it possible to open a program after a user logs in but BEFORE the desktop appears?

Tags: login

I've written a small program that displays an acceptable use policy. Users have a choice of not accepting, whereupon they're logged off, or accepting it, whereupon another screen appears that gives them some information. They click a button on it and the Desktop appears.

Stupid me, I thought I could put this in the user's Startup folder and it would appear immediately after login. But no, the Desktop appears first and a few seconds later my program appears.  I've tried enabling the "Run these programs at user logon" (User Config > System > Logon) Group Policy, but it didn't help. And I've tried using Task Scheduler to run my program after logon, which has the shortest delay between login screen and my program but the Desktop still appears briefly. Is there a way to delay the Desktop's appearance, bypass it and spawn it later, or otherwise be first in line to appear?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to launch the Windows Explorer shell after starting with a different one?](https://superuser.com/questions/644459/how-to-launch-the-windows-explorer-shell-after-starting-with-a-different-one)

Comment: Windows also has a feature to display a legal notice via `legalnoticecaption` and `legalnoticetext` registry keys[.](https://superuser.com/questions/558398/add-paragraphs-to-the-legalnoticetext-before-login-screen)

Comment: @Keltari, I read your post and the thread that ensued. Strikes me that there was no solution other than to skip trying to interrupt the shell and just display an uninterruptible form. That's what I ended up doing, but I that's an abort plan, not a solution. But thank you for the additional insights.